# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked

Tags: c#, flutter, localhost, web-config, flutter-web

I'm trying to connect a flutter web app with C# API with sending and parameter in header "apikey" if I'm sending it the error shows in the browser console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:49986/...' from origin 'http://localhost:61306' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

If I removed the "apikey" the connection goes well without error

Web.config code

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="false"/>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token, apikey" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Dio part in the flutter web app

```
static Dio getDio() {
    Dio dio = Dio();
    dio.options.headers.addAll({"apikey": "xyz"});
    return dio;
}
```

N.B: the request is working well on postman

Is it recommended to disable chrome CORS in development as it's 2 localhosts HTTP or it's not related?
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
postman test
[image]

Comment: Side note: posting Postman/Fiddler OPTIONS request/response may be helpful to someone who know how this settings should be configured to provide an answer (that's not me).

Comment: Do you need the apikey?  It looks like it works without apikey because postman setup a cookie and then when you run the c# it is using the cookie so you do not need the apikey which automatically get sent in the c# code.  Normally when you send a request you get back a response with a status of 200 OK or status of 400/500 indicating an error.  When you do not get back anything then usually it indicates the server did like the headers in the request.  It looks like you request is not secure (HTTPS) so I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare postman headers with c# headers.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thanks for your note, I did add them

Comment: @jdweng, yea I need it as a security for the API access, also in postman apikey is working but when I do send a HTTP requests on flutter app with apikey in the header it shows "blocked by CORS policy" but if I didn't the request goes to the API normally without any errors other than no apikey in header (self-made security check)

Comment: @DasserBasyouni the problem is with OPTIONS - indeed POST would work, but it in no way explains what is missing/mismatched in CORS OPTIONS call (and you need to replay exactly the same OPTIONS call that browser sends, not one that you would like it to send).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, sorry for not getting it, will you explain that a little more?

Comment: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status" - it tells that preflight OPTIONS request that browser sends to verify CORS permissions failed. You need to capture that request -either with Dev tools in browser or Fiddler, or probably Postman (I assume it can do that) and then someone will be able to figure out how your config is mismatcehd to what browser sends. There is no reason to show that POST succeeds as browser does not even try that.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Thanks for the explanation, I got it

Comment: HTTPS use TLS as authentication and when you do not get a response it means the TLS failed.  For TLS to work the TLS version has to be 1.2/1.3.  There was a security push in June by Microsoft that disabled 1.0/1.1 on servers.  So client have to make sure they are using 1.2/1.3.  The certificate encryption mode has to support 1.2/1.3 and be loaded on both client a server.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for the info, I have version 1.1 that should be upgraded now

Comment: Add to code : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;